# Extract single values from an input .txt file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am looking for a way to extract single values of a table like shown below. This is a result file from a calculation. I put them into a subfolder of my working directory and create plots from it. Additionally, I wanted the reader to have a very short look at the "real" data, by providing an additional table which shows an extract of the results in numerical form. In the actual document, t goes up to 20 (seconds), and what I want is to have a table which shows for example values y, z and psi for t=0, 5, 10, 15, 20. 
So I want to set the linenumber and columnnumber in some way, to extract wanted values.

I was looking around in some other threads, but they seem to be about the formatting of the input file or something else, I couldnt really find a path there to follow to realise this. Iam sorry if this is a duplicate, please point me in the right direction then.

Thanks in advance!

```
% 31-Jul-2017 08:41:46 NE=8, 50W 
               t                x                y                z              psi
+0.000000000e+00 +0.000000000e+00 +0.000000000e+00 -5.000000000e+00 +0.000000000e+00 
+1.000000000e-01 +1.481685220e-19 +9.380508188e-03 -5.005996097e+00 -1.937319392e-18 
-7.207098125e-18 +1.745329252e-01 -3.361634670e+01 +1.159338947e-17 +1.978704049e-01
-1.781395404e-01 -1.220128537e-16 -7.332336769e-16 +1.091314344e-15 -3.597376105e+02 
+2.000000000e-01 +3.929558440e-18 +4.110698945e-02 -5.044328318e+00 -1.661176265e-17
```

Comment: What have you tried so far (MWE). You tagged your question with pgfplotstable, do you use it?

Comment: Actually I do not really have a clue how to start. I tagged it, because I used it for other tables (where I imported the whole table, because it was smaller) and it was mentioned in other threads with alike questions.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? pdflatex? lualatex? Would you be able to switch?

Comment: pdflatex, I would like to stay with it if possible. Does \pgfplotstablegetelem do the trick?

Comment: Yes, that would work (at least in the documentation it seems to do what you want).

Comment: \pgfplotstableread[format=file]{file.txt}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{row}{column}\of{\loadedtable} and it can be extracted with \pgfplotsretval. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you use R, another way is Sweawe/knitr: Then is only load the data as a data frame in a object name  (said `df`)  and use `\Sexpr{df$x[2]}` to obtain the value of the variable x in row 2 , printed as `1.4816852 × 10 −¹⁹`

Comment: @Atd you could also write and accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP solved by himself/herself and didn't write an answer (even if invited to).